# How to catch ENOENT in bluebird?

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, promise, bluebird

I like to catch ENOENT in bluebird because of the fs.exists deprecation.

So for example:

```
.then(() => {
    return promisedFs.unlinkAsync(excelPath);
})
.catch(ENOENT ERROR, () => { //do something })
.catch(all other errors, () => {//do something})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/catch.html):

> A filtered variant (like other non-JS languages typically have) that
>   lets you only handle specific errors.
>
> […]
>
> Predicate functions that only check properties have a handy shorthand.
>   In place of a predicate function, you can pass an object, and its
>   properties will be checked against the error object for a match:
>
> ```
> fs.readFileAsync(...)
> .then(...)
> .catch({code: 'ENOENT'}, function(e) {
>     console.log("file not found: " + e.path);
> });
> ```
>
> The object predicate passed to `.catch` in the above code
>   (`{code: 'ENOENT'}`) is shorthand for a predicate function
>   `function predicate(e) { return isObject(e) && e.code == 'ENOENT' }`,
>   I.E. loose equality is used.